# jQuery tubeplayer - Link to stop any video in page

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, youtube-javascript-api

using [jQuery tubeplayer](http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin), how can I set a single button that stop any video embed?

I try the php for render multiples videos:

```
echo '
<div class="video_frame">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".video_frame").tubeplayer({
width: 960, // the width of the player
height: 390, // the height of the player
allowFullScreen: "true", // true by default, allow user to go full screen
initialVideo: "'.$destaque_g['video'].'", // the video that is loaded into the player
preferredQuality: "default",// preferred quality: default, small, medium, large, hd720
onPlay: function(id){}, // after the play method is called
onPause: function(){}, // after the pause method is called
onStop: function(){}, // after the player is stopped
onSeek: function(time){}, // after the video has been seeked to a defined point
onMute: function(){}, // after the player is muted
onUnMute: function(){} // after the player is unmuted
});
</script>
<div>';
```

And call this inside head document tag:

```
$('.stripe_bottom').find('a').click(function() {
$('.video_frame').tubeplayer('stop');
});
```

I wish that any tag 'a' inside div with class 'stripe_bottom' can stop the video inside any div with class 'video_frame'.

The first video is stopped when I click the links inside 'stripe_bottom', but another video will dont stop.

Can anyone help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.stripe_bottom').find('a').click(function() {
    $('.video_frame').each(function(){$(this).tubeplayer('stop');});
});
```